# Assigning groups by multiple rows in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I have a data.table with individuals and some attribute:

```
dt=data.table(individual=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), attribute=c("a","b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "c"))
```

I want to group individuals by the combination of the attribute column so that individuals 1 and 3 with attributes "a", "b", and "c" will be in group 1 and individual 2 will be in group 2. I appreciate any help.

Comment: If you simply want to group the "individual"s (and assuming not a very large number of "attribute"s), you could, also, try something like `library(Matrix); tab = xtabs( ~ attribute + individual, dt, sparse = TRUE); colSums(tab * (2 ^ (0:(nrow(tab) - 1))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method

```
dt[, allAts := Reduce(paste0, sort(attribute)), by=individual
   ][, group := as.integer(factor(allAts))]
```

which returns

```
dt
   individual attribute allAts group
1:          1         a    abc     1
2:          1         b    abc     1
3:          1         c    abc     1
4:          2         d    def     2
5:          2         e    def     2
6:          2         f    def     2
7:          3         a    abc     1
8:          3         b    abc     1
9:          3         c    abc     1
```

The first chain uses `Reduce` to paste together the sorted attributes into a variable named allAts for each individual. The second chain uses allAts to construct a factor variable which is then converted into an integer. You could remove the allAts variable if desired by adding the chain `[, allAts := NULL]` to the end.

---

An alternative suggested by @Frank is to use the data.table `.GRP` keyword together with the `by` value rather than the base R functions `as.integer` and `factor` (because this counter keyword is optimized; see `?GForce`); and to use `order` in `i` instead of `sort` in `j` (because this means fewer calls to sort):

```
dt[order(attribute), allAts := paste(attribute, collapse=""), by=individual
   ][, group := .GRP, by=allAts]
```

which produces identical output.

Comment: Thanks. In case you think it's just a stylistic improvement, it is actually faster, btw (not that it will matter in most cases): http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36126943#36126943